# Google Custom Search API in C#: Paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-custom-search

This is my code for query.

```
String query = 'abc';

CustomsearchService customSearchService = new CustomsearchService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = apiKey });
   Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CseResource.ListRequest listRequest = customSearchService.Cse.List(query);
   listRequest.Cx = searchEngineId;
   search_results = listRequest.Execute();
```

How can I add options like filtering here?
I searched whole internet and github but I couldn't find any sample code or proper documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is like in title about paging then CseResource.ListRequest listRequest has property Start - there you can specify from which result you want to get data (keep in mind only 10 results per query are returned).

So first time you execute it without Start set, and every sub-call to execute should increase Start by 10.

If additional filters - also listRequest contains properties like i.e. FileType, DateRestrict etc.

**EDIT:**
I'm using this page:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list

Comment: Thanks for your message, it doesn't have proper documentation about the parameters, and I can't use which paramter to use.
This is the github url.
https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/tree/master/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1

Answer (score 2):

I changed the code like this and it works.

```
    CustomsearchService customSearchService = new CustomsearchService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = apiKey });
    Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CseResource.ListRequest listRequest = customSearchService.Cse.List(query);
    listRequest.Cx = searchEngineId;
    listRequest.Start = 20;
    listRequest.Num = 5;
    search_results = listRequest.Execute();
```

But it generates error if listRequest.Start = 100 or listRequest.Num = 12

Comment: Num = 12 will not work since there is a limit - maximum 10 results per query. Start parameter will depend on query - might happen it will not work if results count is smaller than 100. Please check count property in response.